# What's the difference between a Home object and a DAO?

Tags: java, hibernate

In a Wicket/Spring/Hibernate project I inherited I find the following pattern:

For each `Entity` there exists an abstract class called `EntityHome` generated by Hibernate Tools which provides methods for finding, persisting, merging, and removing `Entity`. In another package there are classes called `EntityDao` for each `EntityHome` which in most cases simply extend `EntityHome` without adding any additional functionality.

Normally I would create a single generic DAO for handling persist, find, merge, and remove generically and have all DAOs extend this one.

The closest thing to some kind of documentation for Home Objects I found is http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1GA/reference/en/html/framework.html#d0e6756 and what I read there pretty much matches what a DAO should do.

So my question is: what is the difference between a Home Object and a DAO? Is there any at all?

Comment: Sounds like your approach would be the superior one, +1 for a generic DAO with basic functions. On topic, the `Home Object` is probably an own design pattern from the previous developer.

Comment: @Aquillo: I don't believe that it's a pattern from the previous developer as the naming scheme and the comments stem from Hibernate Tools.

Comment: You're correct, I've read the link and I think the `Home Object` is a Hibernate alternative to the `DAO`, though **We can use a Home directly from a JSF page** suggests extra functionality (since this doesn't correspond with the layer model in my opinion).
Maybe the previous developer misinterpreted the meant usage of these type of objects, since he implemented both `Home` and `DAO`?

Comment: Yep, EntityHome is widely used in Seam (same team as hibernate), as it is a view bean layer for entities.